# Concatenate String in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

i have an array which contains strings i.e Array

i tried to concatenate string, but i got an error as "**String is not identical to UInt8**"

```
var titleString:String! = ""

 for title in array {
        titleString += "\(title)"
 }
```

Comment: Why did you make that string optional?

Comment: By mistake. I edited my question

Comment: It didn't work because you declared the `titleAnswer` as implicitly unwrapped optional. Now that you've turned into a non optional, it should work - see my answer below (there's also a better way to concatenate)

Comment: Does your code (after the edit) actually produce that error message? Otherwise your question is unclear.

Comment: @MartinR: You're right.i am getting empty string after concatenate operation.

Comment: @iPhoneGuy: I have rolled-back your question to the initial version, because after your edit the code and the reported error message did not match anymore (and the accepted answer also refers to the code before the edit). Please note that SO is also a reference for future readers, and they would be completely confused otherwise. – If you have a new problem then ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To concatenate all elements of a string array, you can use the `reduce` method:

```
var string = ["this", "is", "a", "string"]

let res = string.reduce("") { $0 + $1 }
```

The first parameter is the initial string, which is empty, and the second is a closure, which is executed for each element in the array. The closure receives 2 parameters: the value returned at the previous step (or the initial value, if it's the 1st element), and the current element value.

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014608-CH5-SW46)

**Addendum** I forgot to explicitly answer to your question: the concatenation doesn't work because you declared the `titleString` as optional - just turn into a non optional variable and it will work. If you still want to use the optional, then use forced unwrapping when doing the assignment:

```
titleString! += "\(title)"
```

**Addendum 2** As suggested by @MartinR, there's another simpler way to concatenate:

```
join("", string)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It works. I am just started learning swift. I am not familiar with Optional Chaining. Will dig into it.

Comment: one more question. I want to display array of strings in multi line in a cell. How can i do that. can you guide me?

Comment: That's more complicated than just concatenating an array of strings. I suggest to search for a good tutorial, raywenderlich.com and appcoda.com have great ones

Comment: i thought of appending "\n" to string and display it in uilabel.

Comment: @Antonio, your solution be further _reduced_ to: `let res = string.reduce("", +)`

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 3, this is how you join elements of a String array:

```
 ["this", "is", "a", "string"].joined(separator: "")
```

Although, `joined(separator:)` is really geared for actually putting a separator between the strings. Reduce is still more concise:

```
 ["this", "is", "a", "string"].reduce("", +)
```

Comment: As of Swift 5, joined() - with no parameters achieves the same thing