# Display Array of Strings into a String of multi line - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, string

I have an array of strings, which i need to convert into single String with multi line

```
 var array = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
 var multiLineString = //convert array to a string
 println("\(multiLineString)")
```

The output should be:

```
  A 
  B 
  C 
  D 
  E
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate String in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583300/concatenate-string-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be something like:

```
var array = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
var multiLineString = join("\n", array)
println("\(multiLineString)")
```

Note that the console does not print this on multiple lines.

UPDATE:
To get the height of the label to display this string:

```
let label = UILabel()
label.text = multiLineString
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.sizeToFit()
println("Height: \(label.frame.height)")
```

Comment: i need to get the total height of a string. so that i can display string in multi lines in a cell. Does 'multiLineString' gives the correct height?

Comment: @iPhoneGuy see my updated answer how to get the correct height of a label displaying this string.

Answer (score 1):

Try `join`:

```
var array = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
var multiLineString = join("\n", array)
println("\(multiLineString)")
```

Comment: i need to get the total height of a string. so that i can display string in multi lines in a cell. Does 'multiLineString' gives the correct height?

Comment: @iPhoneGuy: You seem to mix different problems here. A *string* is just a collection of characters, unrelated to the visual represention. The *height* depends on other parameters, such as the selected *font*.  Perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174007/how-to-calculate-uilabel-height-dynamically (and the related questions) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Correct @MartinR. However, I updated my answer above to display how you can get the height of a label displaying the string.

Answer (score 1):

Since Swift 2.0 this would produce the error:

`Cannot invoke join with an argument list of type (String, [String])`

Use this instead:

`array.joinWithSeparator("\n")`