# Why isn't is possible to append a String! via += operator?

Tags: ios, string, swift, uitextview

As the title says I'm trying to append text to an implicitly unwrapped optional String via `+=` operator which gives me

```
'String!' is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

To let you see what I mean:

```
var myString: String = "Hello "
myString += "world" // works great

var myOptionalString: String! = "Foo "
myOptionalString += " bar" // error: String! is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

however if I append it while the assignment it works

```
var myOptionalString: String! = "Foo "
myOptionalString = myOptionalString + " bar" // works great
```

can anyone tell me the reason for that, or is there something I missed in optionals?

**Update**

```
mySecondOpString: String? = "Hello "
mySecondOpString! += "world" // works great too
```

Comment: I don't know swift very much but be aware that `x+=y` is not semantically equivalent to `x = x+y`. In the first case you have something like *append y to x* (x pointing to a mutable string), and in the second you have *catenate x and y, and associate the result to x*. Optional may change things when append...

Comment: The x = x +y thing is just there so nobody can say "hey try this" but you're right it's not equivalent

Comment: See this for an answer... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583300/concatenate-string-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String! is implicitly unwrapped optional type which is special case of optional type.

As you may know String! is not identical to String. So when you write:

```
var myOptionalString: String! = "Foo "
myOptionalString += " bar" // error: String! is not identical to 'UInt8'
```

it will try to find += operator with String! which it could not and the hence error.

if you explicitly unwrap it (you could say then it defies the purpose) works:

```
 myOptionalString! += " bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in your code. It looks like in Swift's standard library there's no `+=` operator overload made to work with String optionals.

Taken from the standard library, += is overloaded for String (not for String?)

```swift
func +=(inout lhs: String, rhs: String)
```

Just follow this nice [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584627/225503) to view the contents of the Swift standard library to check that

**Note**

Your code will be better written as:

```swift
var myOptionalString: String? = "Foo "
myOptionalString
myOptionalString! += " bar"
```

Comment: Ty but dont worry this isn't copied code. I was working with UITextView.text which is a String!, thats why the question came up